# How to create products programmatically in Drupal 8 commerce

Tags: drupal, commerce

I'm using current commerce 2.x.dev for online store development. It's first project with Commerce 2 for me.

When i started to work on products import, i found that Feeds module does not stable, and i decided to write custom solution for data import (Batch/Queue API data import from CSV/XML sources).

So, at this moment i cannot find any information about correct product entities creation via code. I explored Drupal Commerce documentation section: http://docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/product/products.html but it contains only UI instructions for manual products management.

I think that short instruction for working from code with products / orders entities will be very helpful for developers, especially for developers, who starts working with commerce 2 and have some experience with 7.x commerce.

Answer (score 13):

To create a product programmatically with 3 product variations, use the following code in a custom module:

```
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Drupal\commerce_price\Price;

function my_module_install() { 

// Create variations

$variation1 = ProductVariation::create([
  'type' => 'default',
  'sku' => 'var1',
  'price' => new Price('24.00', 'EUR'),  
]);
$variation1->save();

$variation2 = ProductVariation::create([
  'type' => 'default',
  'sku' => 'var2',
  'price' => new Price('50.00', 'EUR'),  
]);
$variation2->save();

$variation3 = ProductVariation::create([
  'type' => 'default',
  'sku' => 'var3',
  'price' => new Price('115.00', 'EUR'), 
]);
$variation3->save();    

// Create product using variations previously saved

$product = Product::create([
  'type' => 'default',
  'title' => t('Your Product Name'),
  'variations' => [$variation1, $variation2, $variation3],
]);
$product->save();

}
```

I hope that it answers your question. Feel free for more details.

Best regards

Comment: working... but how i will get the id of created  product.

Comment: This contains a lot of good examples https://www.drupal.org/node/2811529 and there is a code recipes section on the drupalcommerce.org website http://docs.drupalcommerce.org/v2/recipes/variations.html

Comment: @amolchallawar `$product->id();`

Answer (score 4):

You need to read this documentation (**[Creating products](https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/products/product-management/code-recipes#creating-variations)**) and do the same way.

**Edited**

```
$variation_blue_large = \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation::create([ 
  'type' => 'my_custom_variation_type',
  'sku' => '001',
  'price' => new \Drupal\commerce_price\Price('10.00', 'USD'),
  'attribute_color' => $blue,
  'attribute_size' => $large,
])->save();

$variations = [
  $variation_blue_large,
];

$product = \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product::create([
  'uid' => 1,
  'type' => 'my_custom_product_type',
  'title' => 'My Custom Product',
  'stores' => [$store],
  'variations' => $variations,
]);
$product->save();
```

Comment: $variation_blue_large = \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation::create([
      'type' => 'my_custom_variation_type',
      'sku' => 'product-blue-large',
      'price' => new \Drupal\commerce_price\Price('10.00', 'USD'),
      'attribute_color' => $blue,
      'attribute_size' => $large,
    ]);
    $variation_blue_large->save();

Answer (score 0):

**Load product with  Multi-pal variation  **

```
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariation;
use Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\Product;
use Drupal\commerce_price\Price;

// Load existing  variations

 $result = \Drupal::entityQuery('commerce_product_variation')
          ->condition('type', 'variation_type')
             ->execute();
  $entity_manager = \Drupal::entityManager();
      $product_variation = $entity_manager->getStorage('commerce_product_variation')->loadMultiple($result);


//Add variation to Product
$product = Product::create([
  'type' => 'hakuro_plate',
  'title' => t('Your Product Name custom New testing'),
  'variations' =>$product_variation,
]);
$product->save();
```